# Glob multiple digits without script-wide shopt extglob

Tags: bash, scripting, glob

I am writing a shell script that iterates over some files.

```sh
for f in $folder-*-something; do
    echo $f
done
```

is generally fine, but I only want to *glob for digits*, so I don't want to match `$folder-1-2-something`

Something that works exactly as wanted is

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extglob

if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
    for f in $folder-+([[:digit:]])-something; do
        echo $f
    done
fi
```

`extglob` can't be turned on in the `if`-block only - it returns `` syntax error near unexpected token `(' `` (somewhere I read a short summary why, but I can't find it anymore). If that would work, I could [reset it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310963) after finishing the relevant lines.

Problem: the script I am extending is part of a big open source project and I don't want to turn on option in the whole >500 line script, since that could interfere with other code.

The option I am leaning towards now is to use the `*`-globbing and skip irrelevant entries.

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. Where can I find good in-depth information about `shopt` and its quirks? I found lots of sites talking about all the options, but I can't even find the two line description on why to put it directly after the shebang anymore.

Comment: Why not `shopt -u extglob` following the `if` block?

Comment: Maybe my example was a bit oversimplified: my block is only one part of an `if`/`elif`/`else`-block and so I would need to activate it for that whole block. This is definitely better than for the whole script, but unfortunately still not quite my preferred solution...

Comment: I believe this answers your second question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45958/275645

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` instead of globbing:

```
find . -regex "./$folder-[0-9]+-something" |
while IFS= read -r f; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

One workaround would be storing the filenames matching the extended pattern into an array and then unsetting the `extglob`. After that, the array must be used, instead of the extended pattern:

```
shopt -s extglob
files=("$folder"-+([[:digit:]])-something)
shopt -u extglob

if [ "$1" -eq 0 ]; then
    for f in "${files[@]}"; do
        echo "$f"
    done
fi
```

or, if you want to restore the state:

```
saved_state=$(shopt -p)
shopt -s extglob
files=("$folder"-+([[:digit:]])-something)
eval "$saved_state"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This also is a good solution, but I think it has a small drawback: in that it separates the logic a bit too much for my liking. Don't get me wrong: this is not your fault, but purely due to the behaviour of `shopt`. I guess it would be best to avoid globbing in this case and use the answer by @KamilCuk.